# How to drop rows in pandas.DataFrame based on values in particular set of columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

From the data frame below, how to delete all the rows where columns `[B, C, D]` all are having null values?

Input data frame:

```
    A    B    C    D
0  20  NaN  2.0  NaN
1   3  1.0  NaN  2.0
2  44  4.0  NaN  NaN
3  67  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  52  3.0  2.0  NaN
5   8  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Desired output:

```
    A    B    C    D
0  20  NaN  2.0  NaN
1   3  1.0  NaN  2.0
2  44  4.0  NaN  NaN
4  52  3.0  2.0  NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would use [`pandas.DataFrame.dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) method with its parameters `how` and `subset`. The code is following.

```
>>> df = df.dropna(how='all', subset=['B', 'C', 'D'])
>>> print(df)
    A    B    C    D
0  20  NaN  2.0  NaN
1   3  1.0  NaN  2.0
2  44  4.0  NaN  NaN
4  52  3.0  2.0  NaN
```

Comment: Thank you.That did the trick.I find this method most comfortable.

Comment: @jjnair, I am glad I could have helped. However, If answer is correct and helpful, also consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it.

Answer (score 3):

Let us try `dropna`

```
df=df.dropna(thresh=1)
```

Comment: Thank you . It does the job for above question.

Answer (score 1):

You can count the (non NaN) value across a subset of columns:

```
df[df[['B', 'C', 'D']].count(axis=1) > 0]
```

It gives as expected:

```
    A    B    C    D
0  20  NaN  2.0  NaN
1   3  1.0  NaN  2.0
2  44  4.0  NaN  NaN
4  52  3.0  2.0  NaN
```

and only focuses on the required columns